# How can you use an already created chromadb collection with a LLM using openai and langchain?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, openai-api, langchain

I already have a chromadb collection created with its documents and metadata.

The problem is when I want to use langchain to create a llm and pass this chromadb collection to use as a knowledge base.

```
langchain_chroma = Chroma(
client=persistent_client,
collection_name=collection.name,
embedding_function=openai_ef,
)

llm_model = "gtp35turbo-latest"

llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
   api_key=openai_api_key,
   api_version=openai_api_version,
   azure_endpoint=openai_api_base,
   model=llm_model)

qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
   llm,
   retriever=langchain_chroma.as_retriever(),
   chain_type="refine"
)
```

When I want to run:

```
qa_chain.run("How many datascientist do I need for a Object detection problem")
```

I got this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-3cdb65aeb43e> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 qa.run("How many datascientist do I need for a Object detection problem")

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/vectorstores/chroma.py in similarity_search_with_score(self, query, k, filter, where_document, **kwargs)
    430             )
    431         else:
--> 432             query_embedding = self._embedding_function.embed_query(query)
    433             results = self.__query_collection(
    434                 query_embeddings=[query_embedding],

AttributeError: 'OpenAIEmbeddingFunction' object has no attribute 'embed_query'
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Can you check python version, langchain version and openai version again? I run sucessfully with my versions:

```
python==3.11
langchain==0.0.339
openai==1.3.4
chromadb==0.4.17
```

Answer (score 2):

I get the same error with chromadb and ollama:

```
AttributeError: 'SentenceTransformerEmbeddingFunction' object has no attribute 'embed_query'
```

My code:

```
embeddingfn = embedding_functions.SentenceTransformerEmbeddingFunction(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")

client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path="/Users/massa/AI/chromadb/")
collection = client.get_or_create_collection(name="asstr.org", embedding_function=embeddingfn)

ollama = Ollama(base_url='http://localhost:11434', model="llama2-uncensored")
langchain_chroma = Chroma(
    client=client,
    collection_name="asstr.org",
    embedding_function=embeddingfn)

qachain=RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(ollama, retriever=langchain_chroma.as_retriever())
d = qachain({"query": sys.argv[1] })
```

I have updated all versions just now. All on python3.11.
Name: chromadb
Version: 0.4.19
Name: openai
Version: 1.3.9
Name: langchain
Version: 0.0.350

THANKS!!